# Index an array within an FFI struct

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

So I am trying to make a module that dynamically detects if you are using Lua or LuaJIT and creates a table or a cstruct depending. Since you can't add metatables to carrays, i have an array called `_m` in my struct.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code, I'll link to the Git repo below.

```
local mat4      = {}
local mat4_mt   = {}

-- Private constructor.
local function new(m)
    m = m or {
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    }
    m._m = m
    return setmetatable(m, mat4_mt)
end

-- Do the check to see if JIT is enabled. If so use the optimized FFI structs.
local status, ffi
if type(jit) == "table" and jit.status() then
    status, ffi = pcall(require, "ffi")
    if status then
        ffi.cdef "typedef struct { double _m[16]; } cpml_mat4;"
        new = ffi.typeof("cpml_mat4")
    end
end

function mat4.transpose(out, a)
    out[1]  = a[1]
    out[2]  = a[5]
    out[3]  = a[9]
    out[4]  = a[13]
    out[5]  = a[2]
    out[6]  = a[6]
    out[7]  = a[10]
    out[8]  = a[14]
    out[9]  = a[3]
    out[10] = a[7]
    out[11] = a[11]
    out[12] = a[15]
    out[13] = a[4]
    out[14] = a[8]
    out[15] = a[12]
    out[16] = a[16]

    return out
end

mat4_mt.__index = function(t, k)
    if type(t) == "cdata" then
        if type(k) == "number" then
            return t._m[k-1]
        end
    elseif type(k) == "number" then
        return t._m[k]
    end

    return rawget(mat4, k)
end

function mat4_mt.__call(_, a)
    return new(a)
end

if status then
    ffi.metatype(new, mat4_mt)
end

return setmetatable({}, mat4_mt)
```

The issue here is that when I try to call transpose, I get the following error:

`'struct 173' cannot be indexed with 'number'`

If you check out `mat4_mt.__index`, I am attempting to detect which type I am working with, table or cdata, and index the array within the struct.

```
local mat4 = require "mat4"
local a = mat4()
local b = mat4():transpose(a) -- Error!
```

The idea is that when you try to access, say, `a[4]`, it should be accessing `a._m[3]` behind the scenes, but that is clearly not happening and I have no idea why.

Thoughts?

https://github.com/excessive/cpml/blob/refactor/modules/mat4.lua

Comment: The above code doesn't work as stated. I had to replace `return new(a)` with `return new(a or {})`. The link is no longer valid. I found this while searching for the error message, so perhaps an answer is still valuable.

Answer (score 0):

It's working, but you lack a `__newindex` metatable entry, causing `out[index] = value` to fail because it's still trying to index the struct, rather than the field it contains. Adding this fixes the problem:

```
mat4_mt.__newindex = function(t, k, v)
    if type(t) == "cdata" then
        if type(k) == "number" then
            t._m[k-1] = v
        end
    elseif type(k) == "number" then
        t._m[k] = v
    else
        rawset(t, k, v)
    end
end
```